# How to read active sheet data in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

I have many sheet in a excel file.I want to read this sheet data which sheet is active. How can I do this ?? do you have you any Sir's ??

Comment: Which excel library you are using with Laravel. it is https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel ?

Comment: what do you wish to achieve?? do you have sheet loaded? or you want automatically to choose default sheet?